# Find the coefficient of the term $x^2$ in $\left(x+\frac 2x\right)^{4}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Find the coefficient of the term $x^2$ in $$\left(x+\frac 2x\right)^{4}$$

This is what I have done so far.

We know $a$ = $x$ and $b$ = $\frac2x$ and $n$ = 4

So what I have done is $4c2$ x $(x)^2$ x ($\frac2x$)$^2$

As we know that $^2$ + $^2$ = 4, and 4 is the $n$ value.

The answer is one though?  What have I done wrong?

P.S. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_3571758741&feature=iv&src_vid=ktDy4ExrctQ&v=--3KJdcbJ0g) was the tutorial that helped me.

Comment: Please use link instead of entering the url.

Answer (score 5):

In the original version, the exponent was $64$

The $r+1$th term will be  $$\binom4rx^{4-r}\left(\dfrac2x\right)^r=\binom4rx^{4-2r}2^r$$

We need $4-2r=2$

Comment: I really don't get what you're saying sorry.  The answer is 1?

Comment: @DebbieWilliams: Nope, the answer is $3816271879373828342811721728$.

Comment: @WillR, Please find the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

The general formula you need to use is:

$$kx^2 = \binom{n}{r} \cdot a^{n-r} \cdot b^r$$

where $n = 4$, $a = x$, $b = \frac{2}{x}$, and $k$ is the co-efficient we're trying to find.

After substituting you get:

$$kx^2 = \binom{4}{r} \cdot x^{4-r} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^r$$

To find the value of $r$ we only need powers of $x$, because we know they must be equal:

$$x^2 = x^{4-r} \cdot x^{-r}$$
Therefore, $$2 = (4 - r) - r$$
$$r = 1$$

Finally, substitute $r$ with $1$ in the original equation:

$$kx^2 = \binom{4}{1} \cdot x^{4-1} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^1$$
$$kx^2 = (4) \cdot (x^3) \cdot \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)$$
$$kx^2 = 8x^2$$
$$k = 8$$

And that's your answer, the co-efficient of the term $x^2$ is $8$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(x+\frac 2x\right)^{4} = \sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{4}{k} x^k \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{4-k} = \sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{4}{k} x^{2k-4} 2^{4-k}$$

If we want the coefficient of $x^2$, then $k=3$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Your task is to find all ways of multiplying $x$ and $1/x$ four times in total so that the degree is $2$.

So this is the same as finding which combinations of $\pm 1\pm 1 \pm 1 \pm 1$ equals $2$.

But after a moment's thought, you see that there is only one solution up to permutations: $1+1+1-1$. This yield four possible ways.

Hence the coefficient is $4 \cdot 2=8$ (since each $1/x$ has a two in front).