# Binomial Expansion help needed with example

Tags: binomial-theorem

Can anyone expand this step by step using binomial theorem:

$(2x-\frac{3}{x^{2}})^{4}$.

Comment: Just use the expansion: $(a+b)^{n} = \binom{n}{0} a^{n} + \binom{n}{1} a^{n-1}b^{n} + \binom{n}{2} a^{n-2}b^{n}+...\binom{n}{n} b^{n}$.

Comment: If you don't know exactly how the binomial theorem works, I advise you to take the time to do this calculation _without_ the theorem. Write down $(2x-\frac3{x^2})\cdot(2x-\frac3{x^2})\cdot(2x-\frac3{x^2})\cdot(2x-\frac3{x^2})$ and start expanding the normal way.

Comment: @Rohan thanks for commenting, could you please do an example using that formula with the question above.

Comment: For example if we take $(2x+3x^{2})^{4} = \binom{4}{0} (2x)^{4} + \binom{4}{1} (2x)^{3}(3x^{2}) + \binom{4}{2} (2x)^{2}(3x^{2})^{2} + \binom{4}{3} (2x)(3x^{2})^{3} + \binom{4}{4} (3x^{2})^{4}$ In fact you could use this same strategy to solve your problem.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: You can have a look at other similar questions on this site to see whether it helps. For example: [Find the coefficient of the term $x^2$ in $\left(x+\frac 2x\right)^{4}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1885813)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use standard Binomial theorem exppansion here.$(a+b)^{n} = \binom{n}{0} a^{n} + \binom{n}{1} a^{n-1}b^{1} + \binom{n}{2} a^{n-2}b^{2}+...\binom{n}{n} b^{n}$.

Now in your case it become:
$$(2x-\frac{3}{x^2})^{4} = \binom{4}{0} (2x)^{4} - \binom{4}{1} (2x)^{3}(\frac{3}{x^2})^{1} + \binom{4}{2} (2x)^{2}(\frac{3}{x^2})^{2}-\binom{4}{3} (2x)^{1}(\frac{3}{x^2})^{3}+\binom{4}{4} (\frac{3}{x^2})^{4}$$

Now I shall let you conclude